# Selecting an unusually named input for jQuery validation leads to syntax error

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to use [jquery.validate.min.js](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) to validate inputs client-side.

This works well if the input name is text only like `<input name="price">`

For example:

```js
$("#foo-post-form").validate({
  rules: {
    price: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }

  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="foo-post-form">

  <label>price</label>
  <input name="price">

</form>
```

---

However, when I try to target an automatically generated input like this one `<input name="foo_fields[15536]">`

I get

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ["

```js
$("#foo-post-form").validate({
  rules: {
    foo_fields[15536]: {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="foo-post-form">

  <label>custom</label>
  <input name="foo_fields[15536]">

</form>
```

---

**I cannot change the name of the input. How can I select an input like that for validation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try enclosing it in quotes. `foo_fields[15536]` represents either an array or an object.

```
$("#foo-post-form").validate({
 rules: {
  "foo_fields[15536]": {
    required: true,
    number: true
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: This works, thanks, I was having trouble with having multiple rules but your answer is the correct answer to the question I asked.

Comment: @Ihazkode Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

I've never used that validation library, but I'll bet it would solve your problem if you modify the input object. Input your key for the field as a string: `'foo_fields[15536]'` instead of `foo_fields[15536]`.

```js
$("#foo-post-form").validate({
  rules: {
    'foo_fields[15536]': {
      required: true,
      number: true
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="foo-post-form">

  <label>custom</label>
  <input name="foo_fields[15536]">

</form>
```

Comment: This works, thank you. I selected the other answer because it was ahead by one minute.